# How to enable bash commands in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, windows-10

I've two Windows machines and both have *bash* installed. However, they differ in the way *bash* starts up:

***Machine 1:***

Typing "bash" starts the bash. Then I can type commands like `ls`.

***Machine 2:***

It seems like it starts *bash* and directly runs `ls` in it, by only typing "ls". After that it switches back to CMD automatically, like this:

[image: like this]

Does anyone know which setting enables the behavior of *machine 2*? Everything looks the same for me. It's a nice feature and I want to enable it on *machine 1* as well.

Comment: It's likely that the PATH environment variable on the second machine points to where the commands are installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bash on Ubuntu on Windows executables (binaries) *cannot* run from *Windows* applications such as `cmd.exe` or `PowerShell.exe` - Windows doesn't even see them as *executable*.**

The **likeliest explanation is that you've installed a separate Unix *emulation* environment such as [GnuWin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/)**, which comes with native Windows binaries.

To see the location of your - by definition *Windows*-native - `ls` executable, run `where ls`, which will probably tell you what product it came with, such as
`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ls.EXE`.

Note that the Ubuntu on Windows binaries are stored in a user-specific manner in
`%LOCALAPPDATA%\lxss\rootfs\bin`, but that is a moot point, given that you cannot invoke them from Windows.

Answer (score 4):

In **Windows 10**, there is a **built-in Linux subsystem** (one of the greatest features of Windows 10). It gives you almost a complete Linux shell for various distributions, and you can almost do anything with it (user mode).

I bet it is installed on your first computer, and you are using that subsystem. In the latest version of this subsystem, you can run both Linux executables and Windows exe files.